# RDLC, too large table is cut but displayed at the same side without line break

Tags: ms-word, rdlc, report-viewer2010

I encounter a problem creating my RDLC file.

I fill a table using a dataset and my report is in landscape view.

When I export to word format, I want the table to be cut and the other parts of the table displayed below the first part. Unfortunately for the moment, my table is cut but the other parts of the table are displayed on the side of the first part:
[image]

So even if I defined a fix size (Letter size) for my report, when I try to print the word export, the size changes due to table size.

[image]

Have you ever encountered the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

'Split the table and put the split part below the original part' i.e 'wrapping' tables. is not a standard behaviour.

I think you'll have to do that manually, i.e. put two tables in the report, with the same dataset, one below the other.

Comment: Hi JeffUK, thanks for your answer. If this is not a standard behavior, why is it working on PDF export?